# Create installer with HM NSIS edit, "fail to execute main script"

Tags: python, installation, pyinstaller, nsis

So I create a simple tkinter app.
I create a .exe with pyinstaller.
I create a .nsi which can create Install.exe
I can give anyone Install.exe, it will install my project.

Problem:
[image: Program installation]

The installation works. If you check "Lancer RT Forms 1.0" the application will compile perfeclty.

BUT

if you try to launch it after, it will always show you this error message.

[image: error message]

Someone know from where it comes from ? any advice on how to debug ? Where can I find explicit error message ?

Comment: More information is needed. How are you starting it when it fails?

Comment: Better is to paste the script, without it it is tough to say.

Comment: That was so sneaky ! I had a try catch on my application so I was thinking it wasn't from the code.
I save the log of the error in a  file in C:\Program Files (x86)\RT Forms\log.json that I create but the program crash because I haven't the right to write.
So my program crash because I try to save the log of the exception... What an irony...

Comment: So know I'm looking for how to get the right to write in the file I created in a "secure area".